# Unable to access NTFS partitions since upgrading to 12.10?

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10. I dual boot between Windows XP and Ubuntu however when I was running my previous version of Ubuntu, 8.10, I could see and access my Windows partitions in Ubuntu. After upgrading, however, I am no longer able to access these partitions.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

someone asked the same question after you. You will find my solution over here
[Drive partition missing after installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276859/drive-partition-missing-after-installing-ubuntu/276875#276875)