# Drive partition missing after installing ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive

Drive partition missing after installing ubuntu, looks like the partitions have merged together and files on the missing partition are not there.

I have opted to use ubuntu instead of windows and i just installed the Ubuntu OS on my 1 TB HDD. Before installing ubuntu, I created three partitions on my Hard drive using the disk management tool in windows. the first partition was about 42 GB in size. The second and third partitions were around 400 GB and 500 GB respectively. Once I booted into the ubuntu os from the DVD, I selected something else from the install screen and I marked the 42 GB partition to be the root and another 100 MB partition which was created by the OS itself as the swap space.

Now, This is the place where I made a mistake, I could find the other two partitions in the same menu not as two separate partitions but as a single partition of about 900 GB space and I had a thought that it will mount them separately once the installation is complete.

After installation, I could not find the 500 GB partition and all its files rather I found the other partition ( having the same name as I gave it when I was using windows ) to be of larger capacity of about 900 GB and those few files I had in them.

Now I really need those files from the missing Partition. Please Help me.

Comment: you have to elaborate this question a bit more with information like what type of partition was it?, what file system it was formatted with? Is it showing up in the disk manager? how have you created this / these partitions? blah blah... so that it can help us understand the issue better & so please help us help you. :)

Comment: Thank You. I have elaborated on my question. Please Help me if you can.

Comment: Hi, please copy and past the complete /etc/fstab file in this question. Thank you for updating the question with some extra info that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

your windows partition is most likely not mounted

type `sudo fdisk -l` to see if it's there.

A shortcut should be on your desktop, all what you have to do is double click it. Your partitions, once mounted show up in `/media/[user]/`

Actually found a simpler solution.

```
sudo blkid
sudo vol_id --uuid X
```

for X= name of mount for example `/dev/sdb2`

Comment: vol_id? vol_id: command not found